# While editing photos, how to add metadata to photos in python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I was wondering is there a simple way to add metadata to my images. When I edit my photos I would like to add some data to image like title, description and keywords. In this way I would avoid using another software. How do I do this in python?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

im = Image.open("sample-image.jpg")

enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)

factor = 1.5
im_output = enhancer.enhance(factor)
im_output.save('more-contrast-image.jpg')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to work with EXIF metadata (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) in python: https://pypi.org/project/exif/

Answer (score 0):

Hi use piexif library for edit the metadata.

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import piexif

o = io.BytesIO()
thumb_im = Image.open("foo.jpg")
thumb_im.thumbnail((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
thumb_im.save(o, "jpeg")
thumbnail = o.getvalue()

zeroth_ifd = {piexif.ImageIFD.Make: u"Canon",
              piexif.ImageIFD.XResolution: (96, 1),
              piexif.ImageIFD.YResolution: (96, 1),
              piexif.ImageIFD.Software: u"piexif"
              }
exif_ifd = {piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal: u"2099:09:29 10:10:10",
            piexif.ExifIFD.LensMake: u"LensMake",
            piexif.ExifIFD.Sharpness: 65535,
            piexif.ExifIFD.LensSpecification: ((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)),
            }
gps_ifd = {piexif.GPSIFD.GPSVersionID: (2, 0, 0, 0),
           piexif.GPSIFD.GPSAltitudeRef: 1,
           piexif.GPSIFD.GPSDateStamp: u"1999:99:99 99:99:99",
           }
first_ifd = {piexif.ImageIFD.Make: u"Canon",
             piexif.ImageIFD.XResolution: (40, 1),
             piexif.ImageIFD.YResolution: (40, 1),
             piexif.ImageIFD.Software: u"piexif"
             }

exif_dict = {"0th":zeroth_ifd, "Exif":exif_ifd, "GPS":gps_ifd, "1st":first_ifd, "thumbnail":thumbnail}
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
im = Image.open("foo.jpg")
im.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save("out.jpg", exif=exif_bytes)
```

By changing the values in the dictionary you can change the metadata. find more examples from this [link](https://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample.html) No need to edit all the values. just keep the values you need to update in the dictionary. Here I have presented all the parameters that you can change.